# pymongo extract document with more than one condition mongodb

Tags: python, json, mongodb, find, pymongo

I'm looking for a command on pymongo that does the equivalent of this mongodb command:

```
db.collection.find({
    $and:[
        {"key1":"value1"},
        { 
            $or: [
                {"key2" : "value2"},
                {"key2": "value3"}
           ]
        }
    ]
})
```

In general I would like to search a document adding more than one condition.

Thanks

Comment: The `$and` is actually implicit in all MongoDB queries so you do not need that wrapping all of this. There really is no difference as python syntax for this is essentially the same. You had a typo of an extra brace `}` as well.

Comment: `<collectionname>.find_one(<condition>)` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything mongodb shell does, but with pymongo. Just use strings!

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 47017)
mydb = client.mydb
mycol = mydb.mycol

mycol.find({
    "$and":[
        {"key1":"value1"},
        { 
            "$or": [
                {"key2" : "value2"},
                {"key2": "value3"}
           ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the API documentation:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find

Just use find(), the spec argument can handle a multi-key dict, so you can just use

```
col.find({"key1":"value", "$or":["key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"]})
```